# How do I access GET/POST from a view helper?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have a custom content element which uses a view-helper that inherits from link action. I want to use specific CSS when this link is "active". One way to do this would be to read `_GET` and check for link variables. Can I access `_GET` in a sane way from a view-helper? Or is there a better way?

Maybe this is impossible because the output of the view-helper will be cached...

I could of course access `$_GET` directly, but will this work with RealUrl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can, the same way as you would do it within controller:

```
$fooInGet    = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET('foo');
$barInPost   = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_POST('bar');
$zeeAnywhere = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('zee');
```

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, because starting with v12, TYPO3 is discouraging access of GET and POST variables via the superglobals and these GeneralUtility functions are marked as deprecated and will seize to exist in TYPO3 13